# Non decreasing function

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Find the number of  $f:A \to B$ where n(A)=m ,n(B)=t, which are non decreasing.
Please help me as i am not able to proceed, we are only provided the number of terms in A&B not the terms hence not able to proceed.

Comment: We need the combinations with length $m$ and $t$ possible entries, so the number of fucntions shoulf be $$\binom{m+t-1}{m}$$

Comment: Can you help me with the background of this formula

Comment: If we choose $k$ elements , each with $n$ possible values, with repititions allowed, then the number of possible choices (if the order does not matter) is $\binom{k+n-1}{k}$, for example, if $k=3$ and $n=5$; we have the choices $$111,112,113,114,115,122,123,124,125,133,134,135,144,145,155,222,$$ $$223,224,225,233,234,235,244,245,255,333,334,335,344,345,355,444,445,455,555$$ , so we have $35$ choices, which is $\binom{3+5-1}{3}=\binom{7}{3}$

Comment: @Peter thanks for your answer, please add the answer in box so i can give upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-decreasing functions correspond with the combinations of length $m$ with $t$ possible entries (repititions allowed and the order does not matter) , hence there are $$\binom{m+t-1}{m}$$ such functions.

Comment: Can you provide me any reference regarding the problem